# how to on select change value should display in JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Echoing HTML Request Parameters</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h3>Choose an author:</h3>
  <form method="get">
 <input type="text" name="usrname"><br>
<select name="car">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>

</select>

<input type="submit" value=Query>
</form>

  <%
  String k=request.getParameter("usrname");
  String s=k+request.getParameter("car");
  out.println(s);
   %>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code. currently I am able to display Input text and on select value on console. Now I want display on select from Option and it should display of input text and select value on Console please implement this or help me to Implement. I am trying to do this but not able to do in `JSP`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simply in `jquery`,

```
$(function(){
    $('select[name="car"]').on('change',function(){
       console.log($(this).val());
       $('input[name="usrname"]').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

**Updated Full code**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Echoing HTML Request Parameters</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script>
      $(function(){
         $('select[name="car"]').on('change',function(){
            $('input[name="usrname"]').val($(this).val());
         });
      });
  </script>      
</head>
<body>
  <h3>Choose an author:</h3>
  <form method="get">
 <input type="text" name="usrname"><br>
<select name="car">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>

</select>

<input type="submit" value=Query>
</form>

  <%
  String k=request.getParameter("usrname");
  String s=k+request.getParameter("car");
  out.println(s);
   %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where i ll cal this Jquery

Comment: Thanx Rohan But where i ll cal this function?

Comment: @RaviJha test the aboce answer I've made changes in it.

Comment: its not display Value On selection change no action fire i want that if i select car then it should display select item on our console

Comment: For displaying in `console` you must add this `console.log($(this).val());` check the above I added it.

Comment: I need to display it <% out.prtinln("Selected item value")  %>

Comment: if You want my Pc acess then please take but help me am stukcing from last 2 days

Comment: please check if any solution u get help me

Comment: Add this after `<select>..</select>` `<span id='dataSpan'></span>`.
Also add this in `onchange` function` after `console` `$('#dataSpan').text($(this).val());`

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing server side with client side. By `console`, if you mean Java terminal console, then you would not be able to do this using JSP code.

You would need to understand how XHR/AJAX works.

Your AJAX code in JQuery would be something like

```
$('select[name="car"]').on('change',function(){
  $.post('POST_URL', {value : $('select[name="car"]').val()}, function(data){
    // do something with response
  })
});
```

Note that above is an example, so it may have typos. Read more about JQuery AJAX in [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

If you mean browser console @Rohan-kumar has already answered your question. From the code snippet it looks like you mean Java terminal.

Comment: I am doing first time and i have tried last 2 days but not able to do so am telling please help me

Comment: please update my code with ajax I have tried last 2 days not able to do please help me